# Weird behaviour when using replace on arab string

Tags: javascript, html, right-to-left, bidi, left-to-right

I am trying to understand why in this snippet, for a given string

```
عروض تبدأ من $minprice
```

I get

```
عروض تبدأ من $5821
```

back :(

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks :)

```
var regExp = new RegExp(/\$minprice/, 'ig');
var string = "عروض تبدأ من $minprice";

console.group();
console.log(
  "new string",
  string.replace(regExp, (matched, offset, originalString) => {
    console.log('originalString', originalString);
    return '$5821';
  })
);
console.groupEnd();
```

Comment: Do not use both regex literal and `RegExp` constructor

Comment: What is your expected output. what is your input?

Comment: That's probably because arab is a right to left language and the engine reverses the string. Just prepare for it or reverse the final string.

Comment: You need to reverse the string. Agree with @NelsonTeixeira

Comment: Thank you people, but I am not sure it does the trick right, take a look and play with it please https://jsfiddle.net/clivend/4v2dz1n7/1/

Comment: This is the [Unicode BiDi algorithm](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/uba-basics). Numbers are weakly directional, but Latin letters are strongly directional.

Comment: thank @RaymondChen for pointing in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you are upset that the **$** sign goes to the right of the number. Don't despair: if you make a Web search, you will find many respectable sites in Arabic where the relative positions of **$** and the western digits are this way, or even mixed `$123` and `123$` on the same page.

As for the order of tokens, the result is absolutely correct, the readers will expect the price to be to the left of the words, because Arabic is RTL language. In many countries, they would also expect to see the Hindic digits, but maybe not with USD sugn attached.

The position of the dollar sign relative to the digits depends on the *directionality* of the span. I.e. if you wrap your the string in `<span dir="rtl">`, it will look different from `<span dir="ltr">`. You can try to return `'$5821'` and `'5821$'` and find which one looks best to you.